# Identify a contact between devices

Tags: android

I want to identify contacts between different devices (with the same google account logged in).

I read the official documentation and there are two attributes in the class [`ContactsContract.Contacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html)  (`_ID` and `LOOKUP_KEY`) that seems to be valid, but in my application are no constants.

So, what is the best way to identify one contact in Android? Is there a constant ID? Maybe with the email? Complete name?

Comment: Do you mean identify a contact in the phone book, or identify the google account the phone is registered with?

Comment: I mean identify a contact in the phone book. For example, I have two mobiles, and I want to identify the contact "John Doe" in both mobiles without confussion (because I can have 10 contacts with the same name)

Comment: I think you may have to take a heuristic approach to this, I don't *believe* there is any identifier that would be unique from google contacts.